# Left recursion of >>= in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I've just read this very interesting article about an alternative implementation for the *Prompt* Monad : http://joeysmandatory.blogspot.com/2012/06/explaining-prompt-monad-with-simpler.html

Here is a simplified code that can be run :

```
data Request a where
    GetLine  :: Request String
    PutStrLn :: String -> Request ()

data Prompt p r
     = forall a. Ask (p a) (a -> Prompt p r)
    | Answer r

instance Monad (Prompt p) where
    return              = Answer
    Ask req cont >>= k  = Ask req (\ans -> cont ans >>= k)
    Answer x >>= k      = k x

prompt :: p a -> Prompt p a
prompt req = Ask req Answer

runPromptM :: Monad m => (forall a. p a -> m a) -> Prompt p r -> m r
runPromptM perform (Ask req cont) = perform req
                            >>= runPromptM perform . cont
runPromptM _       (Answer r)     = return r

handleIO :: Request a -> IO a
handleIO GetLine = return ""
handleIO (PutStrLn s) = putStrLn s

req :: Prompt Request ()
req = do
  answers <- sequence $ replicate 20000 (prompt GetLine)
  prompt $ PutStrLn (concat answers)

main = runPromptM handleIO req
```

A comment in the article mentions that :

> it has a problem that left recursion of >>= takes quadratic time to evaluate (it's the same as the left-recursion of ++ problem!)

I don't understand where the quadratic time (which I checked experimentally) come from. Is it related to lazy evaluation ?

Can someone explain me **why** ?

Comment: The quadratic time does nothing with laziness. It comes from the first clause of the (>>=) definition. Each call to `Ask r c >>= k` will traverse `Ask r c` and all of its subtrees, just like (++) does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the classic [left associated append problem](http://discuss.fogcreek.com/techinterview/default.asp?cmd=show&ixPost=153). You are probably aware that whenever you have a series of left associated append-like functions (I'll use `(++)` here), you run into `O(n^2)` issues:

```
(((as ++ bs) ++ cs) ++ ds) ++ ...
```

It is easy to see that each additional append will have to traverse the entire length of the previously appended list, resulting in horrendously slow `O(n^2)` algorithm.

The solution is to right associate:

```
as ++ (bs ++ (cs ++ (ds ++ ...)))
```

This is `O(a + b + c + d + ...)` where `a` is the length of `as`, etc. or simply `O(n)` in the length of the total list.

Now, what does this have to do with `Free`? Let's suggestively compare the definition of `Free` with `[]`:

```
data Free f r = Pure r | Free (f (Free f r))
data []     a = []     | Cons a [a]
```

While `[]` has values at each `Cons` node, `Free` only has a value at the `Pure` tip. Apart from that the definitions are very similar. A good intuition for `Free` is that it is a list-like data structure of `Functor`s.

Now the `Monad` instance for `Free`, we only care about `(>>=)`:

```
Pure r >>= f = f r
Free x >>= f = Free (fmap (>>= f) x)
```

Notice that `(>>=)` traverses the structure of `Free` until it reaches the `Pure` value, and then grafts (appends) additional `Free` structure onto the end. Remarkably similar to `(++)`!

With this intuition of `Free` as a list of `Functor`, and `(>>=)` behaving as `(++)`, it should be clear why left associated `(>>=)` causes problems.

Answer (score 8):

I feel this is a little easier to explain using the `Free` monad over `Prompt`, though they are very similar.

```
data Free f a = Pure a | Free (f (Free f a)) deriving Functor
```

The `Free` monad is either a *completed* operation marked by `Pure` or an `f`-indexed effect marked by `Free`. If `f` is a `Functor` then `Free f` is a `Monad`

```
instance Functor f => Monad (Free f) where
  return = Pure
  Pure a >>= f = f a
  Free m >>= f = Free (fmap (>>= f) m)
```

This `Monad` instance work by "pushing" binds down through the layers of the `Functor` to reach the `Pure` nodes at the bottom and then applying `f`. What's important about this is that the number of `Functor` layers does not change. To wit, here's an example bind occurring in `Free Maybe ()`.

```
Free (Just (Free (Just (Free Nothing)))) >>= (const (return ()))
Free (fmap (>>= (const (return ()))) (Just (Free (Just (Free Nothing))))
Free (Just (Free (Just (Free Nothing)) >>= (const (return ())))
Free (Just (Free (fmap (>>= (const (return ()))) (Just (Free Nothing))))
Free (Just (Free (Just (Free Nothing >>= (const (return ()))))))
Free (Just (Free (Just (Free Nothing))))
```

We see here a hint of what's to come—we had to traverse the entire tree down to the root just to do nothing at all.

### The "Tree-Grafting" Substitution Monad

One way to see the `Free` monad is to think of it as the "substitution monad". Its bind looks like

```
(=<<) :: (a -> Free f b) -> Free f a -> Free f b
```

and if you think of `a -> Free f b` as converting `Pure` leaf values into new trees of effects then `(=<<)` just descends through the tree of effects `Free f a` and performs substitution over the `a` values.

Now if we have a chain of right associating binds (written using Kleisli composition `(>=>)` to prove that reassociation is valid—Kleisli arrows are a category)

```
f >=> (g >=> h)
```

then we only must descend into the tree once—the substitution function is computed at all of the nodes of the tree. However, if we're associated the other direction

```
(f >=> g) >=> h
```

we get the same result, but must compute the *entire result* `(f >=> g)` before we're able to apply the substitution function in `h`. What this means is that if we have a deeply nested left-associated bind sequence

```
((((f >=> g) >=> h) >=> i) >=> j) >=> k
```

then we're continually recomputing the left results so that we can recurse on them. This is where the quadratic slowdown appears.

### Speedup with Codensity

There's a really strange type called `Codensity` which is related to continuation passing style and the `ContT` monad.

```
data Codensity m a = Codensity { runCodensity :: forall b . (a -> m b) -> m b }

--   Codensity m a = forall b . ContT b m a
```

Codensity has the interesting property that it's a `Functor` even when `m` isn't:

```
instance Functor (Codensity m) where
  fmap f m = Codensity (\amb -> runCodensity m (amb . f))
```

and the unique property that it's a `Monad` even when `m` isn't:

```
instance Monad (Codensity m) where
  return a = Codensity (\amb -> amb a)
  m >>= f = Codensity (\bmc -> runCodensity m (\a -> runCodensity (f a) bmc))
```

We can also round-trip `Monad`s through `Codensity`

```
toCodensity :: Monad m => m a -> Codensity m a
toCodensity ma = Codensity (\amb -> ma >>= amb)

fromCodensity :: Monad m => Codensity m a -> m a
fromCodensity m = runCodensity m return

roundtrip :: Monad m => m a -> m a
roundtrip = fromCodensity . toCodensity
```

but when we do this [something very, very interesting happens: all of the binds become right-associated!](http://www.iai.uni-bonn.de/~jv/mpc08.pdf).